# How to rebuild or refresh slow Motorola Defy

Tags: motorola-defy

My friend has a Motorola Defy which is beginning to run very slowly and reboot itself at random. He's had it for a couple of years.

He doesn't have enough money right now to get a decent replacement so I suggested there might be ways to get a few more months out of the phone.

Installing a brand new/ clean operating system seems like a good plan. I've had a look at Cynogenmod but I'm not sure if that will achieve what we're after.

In the case of a slow Android phone is the best approach to install a new OS? Or are there ways of cleaning up/ speeding up the OS without going to that level?

If we were going to install a new operating system is Cynogenmod the best approach?

I noticed this question explaining how to return the Defy to it's original stock state: [Return my motorola defy to its original state](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6523/return-my-motorola-defy-to-its-original-state)

Comment: The easiest thing would be to simply do a factory reset if he was happy with how it used to run.  If that doesn't work it's probably a hardware issue.

Comment: @MatthewRead - thank you. That definitely seems like the easiest approach. I'll talk to him about that option.